# How to wrap Python functions with try/catch

Tags: python, try-catch, decorator, wrapper

I have about 20 functions that start/end with try/catch statements but how can I create a decorator or wrapper to do it instead of copying and pasting the try catch 20x?

```
def func1():
        TIMER = time.time()
        try:
            print("function1 logic goes here")
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(str(e))
            return str(e)

def func2():
        TIMER = time.time()
        try:
            print("function2 logic goes here")
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(str(e))
            return str(e)
```

I need to wrap all the functions with this:

```
    TIMER = time.time()
    try:

    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(str(e))
        return str(e)
```

Comment: you could also try-catch the parent method which consumes all of your functions?  Though i prefer solving it at the lowest possible level.

Comment: The problem with try-catch the parent method is that error messages don't get cascaded. Each nested function needs to return/relay the error message

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is creating a class and using your functions as attributes. Example

```
def func1():
    print("function1 logic goes here")


class CustomFunction(object):

    def __init__(self, my_func):
        self.my_func

    def exec_func(self):
        TIMER = time.time()
        try:
            self.my_func()
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(str(e))
            return str(e)
```

So, you would wrap your functions like:

```
c_func1 = CustomFunction(func1)
```

And call then like:

```
c_func1.exec_func()
```